# How do I change the KeyFrame duration of my timer when user clicks a button?

Tags: java, javafx, timer, timeline, keyframe

I'm a Java beginner and in my JavaFX controller for my game, I have the following code snippet. It's a button that activates a timer which does something every 5 seconds, it works perfectly fine:

```
double seconds = 5.0;
@FXML
void unlockBtn(ActionEvent event) {
          Timeline timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(seconds), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                  System.out.println("this is called every"+seconds+"seconds on UI thread");
              }
          }));
          timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
          timer.play();
}
```

Then I also have a button that changes the "seconds" variable, the code for it looks like this:

```
 @FXML
void upgradeSecondsBtn(ActionEvent event) {
                seconds = 2.0;
}
```

What it should do: it should update the timer so that it now executes something all 2 seconds instead of 5 seconds. Obviously, this doesn't work.

How can make it so that it changes the rate of the timer when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Timeline timer;

@FXML
void unlockBtn(ActionEvent event) {
    createTimer(5.0);
}

private void createTimer(double seconds) {
   if (timer != null) {
       timer.stop();
   }
   timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(seconds), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("this is called every"+seconds+"seconds on UI thread");
        }
    }));
    timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timer.play();
}

@FXML
void upgradeSecondsBtn(ActionEvent event) {
    createTimer(2.0);
}
```